# Deezer SDK: Invalid redirect URI

Tags: android, deezer

After logging in, I get *You must specify a valid redirect uri*.

Why? Shouldn't the SDK close the Dialog and call the corresponding listener method?

I am using SDK version 0.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server-side bug preventing users from logging in through the SDK was found last week, and it is now fixed.

Sorry for that!